# Oracle Apex 4.2.2: Import csv via button and dynamic action

Tags: sql, csv, import, plsql, oracle-apex

I try to import some data from a csv to a table. The csv lies on the server and i try to make it to an external table to copy its contents to the master data table.
I can't even save the code, without this error:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXTERNAL" when expecting one of the following: := . ( @ % ;

It works fine in the SQL Developer.

```
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE'
  CREATE TABLE  "MY_TABLE_CSV" 
   (    "C1" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C2" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C3" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C4" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C5" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C6" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C7" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C8" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C9" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C10" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C11" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C12" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C13" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C14" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C15" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C16" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C17" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C18" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C19" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C20" VARCHAR2(255)
   )';
   ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
   (
     TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
     DEFAULT DIRECTORY SOME_FOLDER
     ACCESS PARAMETERS (
       records delimited BY newline
       fields terminated BY ';'
       optionally enclosed BY '"'
       lrtrim
       missing field VALUES are NULL
     )
   LOCATION ('foo.csv')
   );
END;
```

The server I work on, runs on Apex 4.2.2.

I already tried to put it in an anonymous block.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I also tried to drop the table before, or even don't create the table, but just delete it's contents. It never works.

EDIT2: I Updated the code. And the Error-Msg.

Comment: You have a spurious quote at the end of the columns list `)';`, the embedded quotes aren't escaped, and you've missed the end quote at the end of the create table command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` function ([Link To Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm)). I even had to use the 'q' to determine, that the "'" is a quote. 
The working code looks now like this:

```
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'!
  CREATE TABLE  "MY_TABLE_CSV" 
   (    "C1" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C2" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C3" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C4" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C5" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C6" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C7" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C8" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C9" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C10" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C11" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C12" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C13" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C14" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C15" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C16" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C17" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C18" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C19" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "C20" VARCHAR2(255)
   )
   ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
   (
     TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
     DEFAULT DIRECTORY SOME_FOLDER
     ACCESS PARAMETERS (
       records delimited BY newline
       fields terminated BY ';'
       optionally enclosed BY '"'
       lrtrim
       missing field VALUES are NULL
     )
   LOCATION ('foo.csv')
   )!';
END;
```

EDIT: I need to create the table every time, because the number of incomming *.csv's is varaible.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to (re)create this every time? When you have created an external table definition you're set: all it needs is a file when you are performing a select on it. If the file changes overnight for example, the external table will still work.

As for the reason of your first error: `CREATE TABLE` is DDL. You can't put this in a PL/SQL block.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Tom. I read about the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement, wich helps a lot, by changing informations in the table and create the table. I'll use the `alter table myapp_schema.DATA_CSV location ( 'new_foo.csv' )` command for changing the csv informations behind the external table.

But i still got an error, when it comes to the `ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL`.
`PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXTERNAL" when expecting one of the following: := . ( @ % ;`